# IncludeJS with timeInterval issue

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Source code.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.open("http://info.finance.yahoo.co.jp/fx/", function(status) {
    if ( status === "success" ) {
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            console.log("executed");
            page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
                var result = page.evaluate(function() {
                    console.log($("#USDJPY_bid").text());
                });
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

---

It works.

```
>phantomjs --web-security=false sample.js
executed
102.6
executed
102.6
102.6
executed
102.6
102.6
102.6
```

I want to get data reloaded by jQuery. First it connect to website and, and repeat executing jQuery with keeping connect.

Number of console.log is increse each time it called. It happens only inside of Includejs. I need it called only once.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. After clearing the interval the missing *hogehoge* are not logged. It doesn't look like there is an issue open. You can report this bug on [github](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues).

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I'm not good at using English. I expect output is 'hogehoge foobar hogehoge foobar...'. Is it Okay? You mean 'hogehoge' is bug?

Comment: No, it wasn't a critique. I wanted to say that this is indeed wrong behavior and a bug. It would be interesting to know why you would actually need this. Do you have multiple scripts that needs loading?

Comment: I understand this behavior is bug. I want to get data reloaded by jQuery. First connecting to website, and repeat executing jQuery for get new data. But times of output is increse each time.

Comment: Reloading the jQuery library will **not** load new data to the page. You have to interact with the page, like clicking links/buttons or directly sending AJAX requests to the server.

Comment: I could get new data using this code. I have edited my sourcecode. Please make sure changing value if you could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely, you will see that jQuery is already included in the page, so you don't need to include it yourself. This is sufficient:

```
page.open("http://info.finance.yahoo.co.jp/fx/", function(status) {
    if ( status === "success" ) {
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            var result = page.evaluate(function() {
                console.log($("#USDJPY_bid").text());
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

If you still want to include your version of jQuery, then you should do this only **once**:

```
page.open("http://info.finance.yahoo.co.jp/fx/", function(status) {
    if ( status === "success" ) {
        var loaded = false;
        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
            loaded = true;
        });
        setInterval(function(){
            if (!loaded) return;
            page.evaluate(function() {
                console.log($("#USDJPY_bid").text());
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

This works on my machine only without the `--web-security=false` flag. Strangely, I have to decouple `includeJs` from `setInterval`.